# Outlier Removal in Non-Normal Data

Tags: outliers, data-preprocessing

I am currently working on a project in which I have to eliminate outliers from non-normally distributed data sets.

The data sets are subsets of a fairly large database (order of millions of observations) segmented into groups ranging from 30-200+ observations based on the type of product being looked at.

The data is pricing data which could be abnormal in the data set due to the possibility of rush orders and other types of abnormal circumstances under which purchases are made which can drive prices above or below a typical range). The difficulty in trying to identify these outlier values is that not every group of observations follows a normal distribution so tests for outliers based on normality are not accurate in testing for outliers in this type of data.

My current approach to this problem is to measure the standard deviation from the mean to flag all values less than three deviations from the mean of the group, this is used to flag the observations for administrative review later.

then I measure skewness using the Pearson's coefficient of skewness. If the value of this statistic is beyond a certain threshold ±.4 then I get rid of the 1st percentile (if skew is lower than -.4) or I remove the 99th percentile of data (if the skew is greater than .4).

This measurement of skew is  repeated with a new measurement of skew each iteration with the same type of observation removal based on the parameter listed in the previous paragraph. The removed values are then given over to administrative review to determine whether they are true outliers with special attention being paid to any values within 3 standard deviations.

is this a good approach to removal of outliers in this case? I don't have much experience with outlier detection in data not belonging to a normal distribution.

so the steps listed explicitly are

1. Calculate deviation from mean for each observation
2. Calculate skewness of the pool of observation 
               if skew>.4 remove 99th percentile observations
               if skew<.4 remove 1st percentile observations
3. values removed are then put under review to determine outlier status with special attention paid to values falling within 3 standard deviations of mean.

Comment: The problem with this is that the SD and skewness coefficient are really sensitive to outliers! Accordingly, I think this is probably a conservative procedure in that outliers tend to inflate these statistics, making it harder to detect outliers. BTW, in the 4th paragraph, you meant to say you flag all those **more** than 3 SDs away -- right?

Comment: No I meant within three standard deviations. I expect that observations beyond 3 standard deviations are much more likely to be true outliers. My fear is that my methodology is too sensitive to outlying values which is why I am considering those within three standard deviations to be possible false flags. 

In the data there are absolute outliers which are not representative of  typical events so the necessity to remove these observations is not questioned. In practice it seems fairly successful I am currently looking for possible alternative methods.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. I hope you have thought long and hard about what happens when you remove outliers, and the risks of not removing them. I think in most analysis situations, removing outliers is a bigger threat to validity. I remember a story from the seventies about a serious El Niño anomaly going unnoticed until much later, because of the outlier-removing algorithm applied to data from the weather satellites.

Comment: What is your intended use of the analysis?  If you are interested in central tendency, why not use a trimmed mean, or a median?

Comment: The data sets can be fairly small so precision in removing what appear to be outliers is needed. That is the reason why I try to remove only values that appear to be lying in extreme tales of my distribution. the trimmed mean method is a little more crude requiring a certain percentile to be removed at both ends although it might remove perfectly valid and non-skewed data at either end.